# Finding out if the object exists in garbage collector

Tags: python, python-3.x, reference, garbage-collection

I have written below program to find out if the object exists in `garbage collector` or not.

```
import ctypes
import gc

def ref_count(addr: int):
    return ctypes.c_long.from_address(addr).value

def find_objid_gc(obj_id):
    for obj in gc.get_objects():
        if id(obj) == obj_id:
            return "object exists in gc"
    return "object doesn't exist in gc"

a = [9, 8, 78]

a_id = id(a)

print(find_objid_gc(a_id))
```

Here, I am getting output `object exists in gc`.

My understanding is that the object should not be existing in gc because the reference to the
object is still existing.

So, output should be `object doesn't exist in gc`.

Comment: `gc.get_objects()` returns objects tracked by the gc wether they are going to be freed or not. The method [`gc.is_finalized(obj)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gc.html#gc.is_finalized) may be what you are looking for if you want to know if an object is going to be freed by the gc?

Comment: Thanks. but in that case `gc.is_finalized(obj)` will always return `false`. Can you provide an example where `gc.is_finalized(obj)` will return `true`?

Comment: Why are you surprised that `gc.is_finalized(obj)` will always return `false`? In your question, you showed the right understanding “*My understanding is that the object should not be existing in gc because the reference to the object is still existing.*” Which raises the question why you started to write a program to test that behavior in the first place. Which scenario did *you* consider to make this program necessary?

Comment: Why not use a `weakref` with a callback to get a signal when an object of interest is about to be finalized?